# Is it possible to run a script upon a user cd-ing to a directory

Tags: powershell

Is it possible in PowerShell to set up a script to run automatically upon someone `cd`-ing to a directory?

I understand all the reasons why that's an awful, terrible, no-good idea but is there a mechanism to support it that does not involve some deep-down file system hacking?

Comment: I think I've seen something similar in bash when using rvm, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I can't think of anything that doesn't involve replacing/overriding `set-location` - all of which would be easily bypassed. The next thought was a `FileSystemWatcher` but that only picks up changes to the filesystem.

Comment: Write a System Level Hook for the cmd.exe (32 and 64 bit) and listen for `keypress`. Something like `while (! Console.KeyAvailable) { ... // do something like run Powershell script when cd command is keyed in }` Can be done in C#.

Comment: Asking a sysadmin buddy about bash he suggests that rvm actually over-writes the `cd` command. So if there's no analog for it in bash I wouldn't be surprised if there isn't one in PS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` is just an alias for Set-Location.  You can remove the `cd` alias (you will need to use -Force IIRC) and then create a CD function.  This is what [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com) does.  However, if you want to handle the case where Set-Location is used directly, you will need to create a [proxy function](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets.aspx) for Set-Location so you can inject your custom code.

Comment: So not without overwriting functions, right? Great link for proxy functions btw

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to remove the built-in cd "alias" but you'll create a *new* CD function.